# Batch file to Copy current datewise folder by skipping/searching a Parent folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy, robocopy

Hi I have been using Robocopy to backup files and now i need to do something like this

"robocopy [D:\test1\21-09-2013\sample.txt] [destination]"

here i have a lot of folders as Test1,test2,...testn. and beneath every test folders there are date wise folder.

My Question is How can i create a batch file to skip the test and copy only folder with Current date i.e something like this

"robocopy [D:\*\21-09-2013\sample.txt] [destination]"

so that it should get all the folders with current date copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "mydate=%date:/=-%"
for /d %%a in (D:\test*) do (
    if exist "%%~a\%mydate%\" (
        robocopy "%%~a\%mydate%" "X:\path\to\destination\folder"
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info.
Can i use Monitor in Robocopy using this

Comment: what 'Monitor' do you mean?

Comment: It is a Copy Option from Robocopy.(It monitors the source directory and copies after detecting some changes in Source)

I Checked and found that the Copy hangs on with the first folder say test1 and it is waiting for the changes to happen in the same folder.

What i exactly want is, It should copy the available(current dated) folders from all parent directory(test1,test2,..testn) and then it should monitor and run again with the changes.
Also I couldn't run this if i scheduled this in Windows task scheduler. Requesting further help....

Comment: can you please put a new question here.

Answer (score 0):

This may work in XP Pro and higher:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%DD%-%MM%-%YYYY%"

for /d /r "d:\" %%a in (*) do (
if "%%~nxa"=="%datestamp%" robocopy "%%a" "destination"
)
```